# Not able to deploy Google Cloud Datalab

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

I have logged into my gmail account. I have given my GAE projects access to Google Cloud and Google Cloud API.

I then went to

https://datalab.cloud.google.com/

I click deploy nothing ever happens even after 30 minutes and clicking on log shows this url https://00e9e64bac0377838a54d60264cce65997c8b2f438815a30ac-apidata.googleusercontent.com/download/storage/v1_internal/b/tournamentparsertest-datalab/o/logs%2Fmain-20151107-21-44-24.txt?qk=AD5uMEsFO2dC4jsdMW0k1Gcc3Q7TC4xr8eTyHIfuBTe07xUG3WqUpOLtYbnmcW5EQDjzkyNeKx2CNpNTLgBY5ZhqaU4IzxR3x88_YR7Hy_rrQR7j8ilRK4FMi7JwZnwMW0heRr1-_awb3JdImjmDgIuGSzQBRqEsHWJupwLC8flsZAToymWG9CtlogUwYz4YOsNVHS01zJ9JoMEyfqGvaqJvmjUhVLqF9g8CgvIpGz6ZNSOOo1x_UYgR9BOUkT60buuWeAtE_Hv9VypbK6upM3SR-MADhTLndy7V5PBY6tCTLDUYQycd4vct2rLmaBgjZxNB8Pu1JvoJe6EIsnh8ADpUHSJq5q5BFi27ls2O09YUWU8W4na0-f9fjFC3-2UFWY6FBmwTGHWtdgP9uDJiOSkUfyAhl70w7VuAQQDybK88DtPVOOE9VvbF13jMieYusHI9O9dFTloPBXCoJGDhhyWhgrozCs5g5XM7oC3X_aIV4-ZXGzW9WZ4jYlDMU2FdCZ-lCKm_d9Xt8n3OP6ls_gxkRZ9tGK6IqJaIL0TOSDPlNqvo4fJSnLwY49ZCFw8pm2z1Zv_xnIaCtWSdOKyM9aU9uq6CkB6pZZxufUuxMGScxb2qcLxTkLcWV5mFN6z7fZvIxz30BtCfoyUNsYwFqSORzyiR23V88GbjsjGPN16kTphoWWnBrde_FQ2mO-SwdnTMmmEvGGIeyNgvEREuXfME1tpweZOokl8umReoTBB13FwVdL75-55bhxLgiSLaB_sinHy45pntUvKyPZHYHd6eIps-89kSOsGwJAlAJUcaOW8oIV7l4DYFUSTpVd9_bBOH0TfZeH8QZRGee_kbPjLYCj2PGr_h_GodOTEt7VRb4VJysQwyqsg  with "Not Found" on the page.

If I delete the vm's in cloud storage. 
Try to redeploy and then the log shows this. Pleas let me know what next step should be.

Nov  7 21:49:52 datalab-deploy-main-20151107-21-49-16 startupscript: Running startup script /var/run/google.startup.script
Nov  7 21:49:52 datalab-deploy-main-20151107-21-49-16 startupscript: Ensuring storage bucket...
Nov  7 21:49:54 datalab-deploy-main-20151107-21-49-16 startupscript: Creating gs://tournamentparsertest-datalab/...
Nov  7 21:49:55 datalab-deploy-main-20151107-21-49-16 startupscript: Start deploying Datalab instance main...
Nov  7 21:49:55 datalab-deploy-main-20151107-21-49-16 startupscript: Setting up source repository branches...
Nov  7 21:49:56 datalab-deploy-main-20151107-21-49-16 startupscript: creating default repository...
Nov  7 21:49:56 datalab-deploy-main-20151107-21-49-16 startupscript: Step checking default repository succeeded.
Nov  7 21:49:57 datalab-deploy-main-20151107-21-49-16 startupscript: creating master branch
Nov  7 21:49:57 datalab-deploy-main-20151107-21-49-16 startupscript: Initialized empty Git repository in /master_branch/.git/
Nov  7 21:49:57 datalab-deploy-main-20151107-21-49-16 startupscript: [master (root-commit) 1c57abe] master creation
Nov  7 21:49:58 datalab-deploy-main-20151107-21-49-16 startupscript: fatal: remote error: Repository not found.
Nov  7 21:49:58 datalab-deploy-main-20151107-21-49-16 startupscript: You may need to create a repository for this project using the Source Code tab at https://console.developers.google.com
Nov  7 21:49:59 datalab-deploy-main-20151107-21-49-16 startupscript: Step creating master branch failed.

Comment: When going here I receiceive failed to load https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/source/overview?project=tournamentparsertest&pli=1 https://gyazo.com/b086b0f2bf50589e8064cdf3c8825de2 It says my cloud repository is empty when going to Development/Source section This is a an existing project should I be creating a brand new blank project and deploying to it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the source repository within the specific project is failing to be initialized.

Can you check the status (and possibly delete the repository, assuming it is empty) before trying again. Specifically, try the following:

Go to the developer console and navigate to the Development/Source section (https://console.developers.google.com/code/develop/browse/) to see if there is any indication of possible issues. You can delete the existing repository by clicking the Settings button on the upper right, and choosing Delete. The repository will be recreated when you deploy Datalab.

You mentioned you have a GAE project and have given it access to Google Cloud. Is this an older AppEngine project? It might be worth checking if the source repository feature has been enabled as well -- see https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/source/overview?project=[your project id] and make sure the API is enabled.

Let us know if that gets you unblocked.

Comment: When going here I receiceive failed to load

https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/source/overview?project=tournamentparsertest&pli=1

https://gyazo.com/b086b0f2bf50589e8064cdf3c8825de2

It says my cloud repository is empty when going to 
Development/Source section

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible for you to try a new project, please do. A new project comes with a new source repository so it might get you unblocked.

For your current project, maybe we could do a quick test to see if the source repository is working:

1. Authenticate by running "gcloud auth login" in a command shell.
2. Run the following:

export ACCESS_TOKEN="$(gcloud auth print-access-token)"
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" https://source.googleapis.com/v1/projects/tournamentparsertest/repos

If the repo is there, it should print a JSON response with the repo details. Then we can run the following to delete it:

curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" -X DELETE https://source.googleapis.com/v1/projects/tournamentparsertest/repos/default

Now either way the repo has gone. Let's try creating the repo manually by running:

curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"vcs":"GIT"}' https://source.googleapis.com/v1/projects/tournamentparsertest/repos

And then run the previous command to make sure the repo is created successfully. Try deploy Datalab again.

Let me know if it works!